# Which Pointers from WordNet are Used for Synset in NLTK

Tags: nlp, nltk

I'm trying to create a custom parser for wordnet and hit a roadblock. I see that there are tons of different pointer_symbols and lots of them seem almost like synonyms but not exactly synonyms. I'm trying to extract the synonyms for each word and I'm not sure which pointers should be considered. I couldn't find anything through NLTK as well as to which pointer_symbols does it use for it's task.

Any hints on what should I use?